# How to aggregate string array in c

Tags: c, arrays, string

Here is a an array:

```
char *a[]={"I", "LOVE", "C", "PROGRAMMING"};
```

How to aggregate this array to a string in c?

That is,

```
char b[]="I LOVE C PROGRAMMING";
```

I had tried to use memcpy for each string, but I have no idea to add spaces in each other.

```
int width[4];
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    width[i]=strlen(a[i]);

//aggregate the msg length
int agg_len[4];
int len_w = 0
for (no = 0; no < 4; no++) {
    len_w += width[no];
    agg_len[no] = len_w;
}
//compose msg
memcpy(b, a[0], width[0]);
for(idx = 1; idx < 4; idx++)
{
    memcpy(b+agg_len[idx], a[idx], width[idx]);
}
```

and the result is "ILOVECPROGRAMMING"

How to fix it to "I LOVE C PROGRAMMING"

I have tried add spaces but failed with wrong memory address when I using memcpy

because it need add 1 length after each step (" " need 1 length)

Comment: Conceptually, joining the strings `"I"`, `"LOVE"`, `"C"`, `"PROGRAMMING"` with spaces is the same as joining the strings `"I"`, `" "`, `"LOVE"`, `" "`, `"C"`, `" "`, `"PROGRAMMING"` without.  Does this help?  But I think you can simplify your approach: Just concatenate the strings as you go.  There is no need to fiddle the lengths in advance.  Also seems like [`strncat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncat) could help you.

Comment: You need to measure the lengths in advance so you know how much memory to allocate to `b`.  But your code is pretty close to working, you just need to insert a space (and therefore `memcpy` to a later offset for each word, e.g. `b+agg_len[idx]+idx`)

Comment: Thanks to @MattMcNabb , but I failed with that. The offset I added is not working correctly.

Comment: check your code and make sure you are using the right offset. Maybe walk through the code in a debugger, or on paper, checking your numbers.

Comment: thanks! I will find out where the problem is!
thanks for your advice, @5gon12eder.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to find the number of strings (num) in the array and make the new array have an extra length of num - 1 so that when you compose the message, simply add the spaces after you finish copying each word.

Comment: Actually, the total length of the new array needs to be the sum of the N lengths plus N (not N-1) as you need a terminating null byte too.

Answer (score 1):

Make enough buffer and use strcat. Space shoud be put for except last.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char *a[]={"I", "LOVE", "C", "PROGRAMMING"}; 
  char buf[1024] = {0};
  int i, len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    strcat(buf, a[i]);
    if (i < len - 1)
      strcat(buf, " ");
  }
  printf("[%s]\n", buf);
  return 0;
}
```

Probaly, your want is `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` ?

If you must use `**a` instead of `*a[]`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char *a[] = {"I", "LOVE", "C", "PROGRAMMING", NULL}; 
  char buf[1024] = {0}, **p = a;
  while (*p) {
    strcat(buf, *p);
    if (*p && *(p + 1))
      strcat(buf, " ");
    p++;
  }
  printf("[%s]\n", buf);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works! but my a array actually is char **a, that's why I don't use sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]). Is there another way to get the len? The length of a is unknown, so I use char **a to realloc each step.

Comment: If you must use `**a` instead of `*a[]`, you have to put NULL into the array, and `a[i]` is NULL or not.

Comment: @user2722174: What do you mean 'my `a` array actually is `char **a`'?  That's not what you showed in the question.  For a `char **`, you have two options: (1) the calling code tells you how many entries are in the array, or (2) the last entry in the array is a special value, conventionally the NULL pointer.

Comment: To @JonathanLeffler, what I showed in the question is trying to know how to add spaces. So I make a simple example. But in my data, I need to split the input string to a. So I use char **a to realloc each step when I split input str and copy to a. according to the steps, I have already know the len of a,Thanks to you!!

Comment: @Shinline: congratulations on choosing a user name.  That means, I think, that you have option (1) of the two I outlined — you know from some other source (calling function or whatever) how many entries are in the `char **a` array.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char *a[]={"I", "LOVE", "C", "PROGRAMMING"};
    size_t a_size = 4;
    size_t width[a_size], total_size = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<a_size; i++){
        total_size += (width[i] = strlen(a[i]));
    }
    char b[total_size + a_size];//between ' '(a_size-1) + NUL(1)
    char *p = b;
    for(int i=0; i<a_size; ++i){
        if(i)
            *p++ = ' ';//put space
        memcpy(p, a[i], width[i]);
        p += width[i];
    }
    *p = '\0';//put NUL
    printf("'%s'\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```